# PHP thread can't unlink files?

Tags: php, multithreading

When creating a new PHP child thread it becomes unable to delete files using unlink(). is there a good reason for that limitation or I'm forgetting something?
I get a worning:

> Warning: unlink(downloads/1e6f6fa1c0552a1af9058f10216b40e8): No such
>   file or directory

although the file is created in the destination folder, and when I run the same command outside the thread function it deletes the file as it should.

//multithreading class

```
<?php    
class download extends Thread {
public $i;
    public $res;
public function __construct($s){
    $this->i = $s;
}
public function run() {
try{
    $url = "http://my.link.com/{$this->i}";
    set_time_limit(0);
    $id = md5(uniqid());
    $tempName = md5($id.time());
    $tmp = "downloads/{$tempName}";
    $fp = fopen (dirname(__FILE__) . '/'.$tmp, 'w+');
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);
    require('scanner.php');
    $results = scanfiles($tmp);
    unlink($tmp);
    $this->res = $results;
}catch(Exception $e){
    $this->res = '0';
}}} ?>
```

Comment: please include your code

Comment: There's an excellent reason - namely, you made a mistake with file paths for opening and unlinking. Why do you mix relative and absolute paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Into fopen you're passing absolute path (`dirname(__FILE__) . "/{$tmp}"`) while into unlink relative path, just use abslute everywhere and it should work. Btw you can use just `__DIR__` instead `dirname(__FILE__)` since PHP 5.3.

Comment: I used to run the same code without threading and it was working fine, then I moved it into the thread class and it just crashed.

Comment: This solved the problem, although I don't really know why. thank you.

Comment: I don't have any experience with pthread, anyway if its real threading then it shouldn't be a problem. When you was trying to run this code without threading, was it located in same file? I mean relative path will be rather relative to main script, not included files.